# What happens when iterating over a Java LinkedList using the native foreach syntax?

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm trying to understand the basic behavior of Linked List when iterating over it using the foreach syntax. Let's say the LinkedList contains A, C, B, D added in that order, so that the order should be exactly that -> A-C-B-D. If I iterate over the LinkedList using foreach (which uses the Iterator implicitly as I udnerstand it), does the contract guarantee that the items will be retrieved in order? The API doesn't actually seem to say this, though maybe it's just too obvious to mention? I'm looking at the Java 7 API: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html
The API mentions that the iterator is fail-fast, and goes into a lot of detail about that, but says nothing I can see about the iterator guaranteeing the order of the Linked List.

Comment: well, I guess you can derive it from the `List` javadoc: `An ordered collection...`. Then `LinkedList` states: `Doubly-linked list implementation of the List...`. So, if `List` is ordered then `LinkedList` is ordered too. Compare it with `Set` and `LinkedHashSet` and you will `LinkedHashSet` cleary mentions: `...This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is the order in which elements were inserted into the set (insertion-order)...` which is different from the `Set` interface

Answer (score 0):

> The API doesn't actually seem to say this

Oh yes it does. ["Returns an iterator over the elements in this list (in proper sequence)."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSequentialList.html#iterator())